# How can I get signposts when driving with HERE android SDK?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Android SDK. Is there any way to get Signpost when driving. like stop sign ahead my car? traffic lights, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a signpost feature included in the guidance package of the HERE SDK:

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance-events.html

"The 2D Signpost feature provides images that illustrate road signposts. For example, as a user approaches a fork on a highway, your application can use show a preview of the instruction signs above the highway. "

But this is mainly about highway exits and highway junction/lane orientation, and not about stop signs or traffic lights as you mentioned in your example.

If you need these information you should consider using the Platform Data Extension on top: https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/overview.html